# different front and rear tires for bike packing

Tags: road-bike, tire, touring, gravel, bikepacking

I plan to do a 1000 km bike packing/touring  around West Nusa Tenggara, Indonesia. The route consist of 70% tarmac (transition between towns through jungle mountain pass) and 30% gravel (Smooth,chunky fist-sized, sand mostly to get to my destination like beaches, cliff, waterfall, etc.). climate here is dry all year round. i have 2 options for tire type selection,
first one is both tyre using regular gravel tyre (knobby, maybe vulpine or cinturato H), and the second is to swap the front with semi slick tyre (same size, maybe Byway or pathfinder).
Main things to consider is:

1. does it change the balances of front-rear grip esp. while cornering and descending (climbing mostly depends on rear wheel traction)
2. how much gains (marginal) do i get from the semi-slick tyre
3. which setup is more efficient overall (comfort, safety, speed, etc.)

Comment: In MTB people use different tyres for front and back all the time. But your questions are too many and very specific and look like a better fit for a discussion forum. 1000 km does not sound that much, if in civilized world, I would not bother with a spare tyre.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I live in a fairly densely populated country, and often do carry a tyre. I've used it a couple of times, and wished for it once when I didn't carry it (a blowout too close to the bead for a boot, and longer than the boots I carry). Even here in the UK, most of my riding distance is more than 2 hours walk from a bike shop or public transport to get to one - and many aren't open on Sundays. Taxis won't take bikes and it can be hard to get one in a rural area. I'm not saying you have to, but it's often a good idea to carry a tyre

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава the road is good, but between village it is around 50km and there's no transportation (middle of jungle, no ppl at all, mountainous terrain). well, let's simplified the question to which one to pick between  front semi -slick or regular tire for marginal gains

Comment: For the question about performance gain, the answer is always looking up at bicyclerollingresistance.com. For tires mentioned in the question, Cinturato H has lower rolling resistance than Pathfinder.

Comment: BTW if you are going to carry a tyre, it doesn't have to be the same as you'd choose ideally.  I carry a folding 28mm Durano Plus for road (otherwise 32mm) and gravel (37mm), and have even carried it on the MTB, when it would have been a challenge squeezing the tube in.

Comment: What's your target daily road distance/speed?  If the off-road is important and challenging, it might be worth optimising for that, but if you're in a hurry on the road, you might accept a greater risk of having to walk some off-road sections

Comment: @ChrisH well i target around 80-100k a day because the elevation gain can get very high (i planned the route and the max in one day is 2000 meters for 100k ride).  The trip is 2 weeks overall with couple days off the bike to enjoy the spot. The off road is challenging (steep gradient, loose surface) but the road is very smooth, that's why i'm in dillema here. I have a spare used tyre from when i bought my bike so i'll bring them in case i need it, still usable

Comment: @RavidasK good, that's a level I understand.  I did a 200km mixed-surface ride on my gravel bike (37mm WTB Riddler) recently, but didn't  have to ride again the next day. With such hilly rides, and a bit of time to spend on the ride, I'd probably optimise for the off-road, on the basis that you won't feel the loss of speed on road.  Those gravel tyres are faster than the WTB Nano I fit on on my MTB for gravel rides, and much faster indeed than my MTB knobblies; they're not much slower than some road tyres

Comment: @ChrisH Have you tried all of WTB tyres?? If so can you suggest which to used in my case here, i opt for vulpine and byway combination for both are atated for speedy ride, but what do you think is kost suitable for dry condition with mixed roff road terrain?

Comment: @RavidasK no, I tend to use what I have until it's used up, then decide whether to try something new.  I'd probably get the Cinturato for both, from the options you listed, but mainly based on looking at the tread and guessing how it would ride

Comment: @ChrisH BTW here's some post for the route i'll be taking to put into consideration  [Wheels to wave](https://instagram.com/wheels.to.waves?igshid=NzZhOTFlYzFmZQ==)

Comment: Just wanted to comment on "*climate here is dry all year round*": are you sure about that? If you visit during the wet season you might get a few days of heavy rain in a row if you're unlucky (I was when I visited the area). Perhaps you're already familiar with the site, but you can check [weatherspark](https://weatherspark.com/y/131194/Average-Weather-in-Sumbawa-Besar-Indonesia-Year-Round#Sections-Precipitation) to get a feeling for what to expect in terms of climate.

Comment: Yeah i'm aware there might happen, i'm in this region now but only 2% rainy days, and most of the are under 30 minutes. To take precaution i'll do the trip on dry season tho, and if it rains i'll refrain from taking those off roads where it might get tacky and dangerous and stick to the tarmac/more safe off roads, thx for the weather check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, having different tires in common in MTB, and is also discussed in the context of [gravel racing](https://www.theproscloset.com/blogs/news/why-dont-gravel-riders-mix-tire-tread-patterns).

The principle is: grippier tire front, less rolling resistance rear. The reasoning is that there is more weight on the rear, so the rolling resistance is mostly influenced by the rear tire. But when you brake or corner, the weight is transferred to the front. Having grippier tires allows to have more control when you need it. Because there's less weight on the front rear when riding, the impact on rolling resistance is lower.

So having a semi slick front and a gravel tire rear might not be the most optimal combination.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reference you add, helps a lot in sorting my mind out, but one thing still bug my mind, that is if i use semi slick in the rear, wont i be more prone to sliding and skidding when i climb, esp in loose terrain? Does semi slick tire holds up well in climbs as knobby tire?

Comment: @RavidasK big loose lumps (unless wet and rounded) are quite OK on semi-slicks.  Mud and small loose stuff is where tread is needed.  But if you lose traction on the back climbing, you put a foot down, get off, and push.  If you lose traction on the front cornering, you probably crash.

Comment: For wear it can also be beneficial to have a slick tyre in the rear. Most of the wear happens on the rear tyre and knobs can wear down quickly.

Comment: @Michael gravel tyres seem better than true knobblies in that regard (I ride my MTB to the trail centre on road and that's killing my back tyre).  But you're right, or course.  Picking something with some grip but more rubber than air touching a flat surface might be good.  I used to use Marathon Mondial on my tourer for that, before I got a gravel bike